# Why use promise or async/await on child processes in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await, child-process

I am using child process `exec`, which I believe is asynchronous based on the documentation, to run a Python script in my Node.js server.

However, when I searched on the web and Stack Overflow, I saw many instances of using promises and `async`/`await` for child processes in Node.js.

It just made me curious that if the child processes (`exec`, `execFile`, `spawn`, `fork`) are asynchronous functions already, why would you want to use promises or `async`/`await` on them.

Comment: Promises does not make a function asynchronous. If you use a promise on a synchronous function it would still be synchronous (though the `then` method will not trigger synchronously). Promises is a design pattern for handling asynchronous operations just like MVC is a design pattern for handling GUI operations.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, slebetman.  Please let me clarify my question.  My understanding was that when you want to make something to run asynchronously, you can use either i) callbacks, ii) async/await or iii) promise/then.  So, if "that something" (childprocess exec, spawn, execFile, fork) is already asynchronous, why would you try to make it asynchronous again by using async/await or promise/then?

Comment: Let me also link the documentation for the childprocess:  https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: dude async/await this will be useful when one of your asynchronous function want to wait for some of the result ...like executing a query,based on the result your code should work like that

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. If you want to make something run asynchronously you either use timing functions (`setInterval`, `setTimeout`, `setImmediate` or `requestAnimationFrame`) or write code in C. If you want to handle responses or wait for asynchronous operations then you can use callbacks, event emitters, or promises (with async/await allowing you to handle promises in a more readable manner). Since childprocess functions are asynchronous the author must choose how to let users use them - either via callbacks or promises etc.

Comment: Thank you slebetman.  Your comment helped me getting clearer grasp on running scripts asynchronously; I think what you mentioned are the fundamentals.  Really appreciated.

Comment: I want to add that "callbacks" aren't asynchronous "per se", that means that there are callbacks synchronous and other that are asynchronous. It depends the "closure" they call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really depending upon your need..please find below code for clarification about async/await

```
Without async/await
function (){
      rs = f1(); 
      rs1 = f2();  // this function executes without waiting for f1() 
      return rs + rs1;
}

With async/await
function (){
      rs = await f1();   
      rs1 = f2();        // this function call wait untill f1() executes
      return rs + rs1;
}
```

Comment: Well understood now.  Thanks for the illustrating the cases.  So I guess it really depends on the circumstances around using child processes.  Much appreciated!

Comment: async/await as Promises are sintax sugar over  asynchronous functions

Answer (score 1):

> Why would you want to use promises or async/await on them?

by "them", you mean the child process, yes the child process is asynchronous. Then we can ask this question:

> Why would you want to use promises or async/await on asynchronous function?

One reason is to avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), make the coding structure easy to read by making them look synchronous.

There is 2 type of function execution: synchronous and asynchronous.

There is 3 way to call the asynchronous function: callback, promises, async/await.

Hope that helps your understanding.

Comment: Hi egig, much appreciated for your answer.  You clarified the exact point that I was curious about.  I guess avoiding callback hell could be the major benefit... I havent encountered it yet, but some examples of callback hells I saw on the web are really awful.  Hope you have a nice day!

Comment: "One reason is to avoid callback hell, make the coding structure easy to read by making them look synchronous." This is partially wrong as assume that all "callbacks" are asynchronous and that is not the case in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to previous answers some consideration why not using callbacks that do use asynchronous functions(setTiemout, setInterval etc) as are child processes and so the answer why sometimes you can find more Promises or async/await patterns. Those are well described here https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_promises.html:

- The type signatures of Promise-based functions and methods are cleaner: if a function is callback-based, some parameters are about input, while the one or two callbacks at the end are about output. With Promises, everything output-related is handled via the returned value.
- Chaining asynchronous processing steps is more convenient.
- Promises handle both asynchronous errors (via rejections) and synchronous errors: Inside the callbacks for new Promise(), .then(), and .catch(), exceptions are converted to rejections. In contrast, if we use callbacks for asynchronicity, exceptions are normally not handled for us; we have to do it ourselves.
- Promises are a single standard that is slowly replacing several, mutually incompatible alternatives. For example, in Node.js, many functions are now available in Promise-based versions. And new asynchronous browser APIs are usually Promise-based.